# Как правильно организовать мультиязычность Symfony4

Tags: php, symfony, symfony3, symfony4

Сталкнулся c непониманием, как можно организовать мультиязычность в symfony4. Идея такая, есть адрес, например site.com. Если он без префикса локали, брать дефолтную локаль, если он например site.com/en/, брать английскую локаль. Как правильно сделать так, что бы локаль сетилась из префикса, а соответсвтенно подтягивались все переводы и т.д. Ну и, если есть возможность, все урлы были с префиксом.

Comment: https://symfony.com/doc/current/best_practices/i18n.html, https://symfony.com/doc/current/translation.html

Comment: спасибо за Ваше потраченное время, но дока ни продвинула меня ни на шаг

Comment: Здесь подробно описано как это разрулить https://symfony.com/doc/current/translation/locale.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Как указывал @u_mulder выше в [документации](https://symfony.com/doc/current/translation.html). В symfony есть бандл `Translations`. И весь механизм сводится к таким пунктам.

- настройка translations;
- включение локали в URL;
- Базовый перевод;
- Создать файлы перевода для каждой поддерживаемой локали;
- перевод в шаблоне.

## Настройка translations. Установка

```
composer require symfony/translation
```

## Настройка translations. Конфигурация

В документации предлагают создать некий `config/packages/translation.yaml`, а потом его подключить в `config.yaml`. Я предлагаю прямо сразу в конфиге в секции `framework` добавить

```
framework:
    default_locale: 'ru'
    translator:
        fallbacks: ['ru']
```

Где `default_locale` локаль по умолчанию, а [`fallbacks`](https://symfony.com/doc/current/translation.html#fallback-translation-locales) - это резервная локаль. 
То есть локаль на которую будет переведен ключ в случае, если нигде не нашлось перевода.

## Включение локали в URL

Механизм поддерживается системой маршрутизации с использованием специального параметра `_locale`. Добавляем в рутовый конфиг роутинга следующее:

```
# config/routes.yaml
main:
    path:       /{_locale}
    controller: App\Controller\MainController::index
    requirements:
        _locale: ru|en
```

Теперь роутинг будет формироваться example.com/ru. А так как ru по умолчанию, то example.com должен сделать редирект на example.com/ru. Соответсвенно, обращение к 
какому-нибудь `example.com/ru/home` нужно добавить :

```
# config/routes.yaml
    main:
        ....

    home:
        path:       /{_locale}/home
        controller: App\Controller\HomeController::index
        requirements:
            _locale: ru|en
```

Но если нам, допустим, понадобится, к примеру, `example.com/ru/home/room`. Опять писать 
правило только для другого **метода** `HomeController`? Нет, в symfony можно настроить это глобально:

```
# config/routes.yaml
main:
  resource: "@AppBundle/Resources/config/routing.yml"
  prefix:   /{_locale}
  requirements:
    _locale: ru|en
  defaults: { _locale: ru}
```

## Базовый перевод;

этот пункт для случаев если нужно переводить прямо в коде.

```
//MainController
use Symfony\Contracts\Translation\TranslatorInterface;

public function index(TranslatorInterface $translator)
{
    $translated = $translator->trans('Some text');

    // ...
}
```

## Создать файлы перевода для каждой поддерживаемой локали

По умолчанию Symfony ищет переводы в:

> translations/ в корне проекта;
>   src/Resources/BUNDLE_NAME/translations/ в конкретном бандле **depricated**;
>   Resources/translations/ в папке ресурсов.

Также важно указать имя файла перевода. 
По умолчанию создайте файлы в папке `translations/`  `messages.ru.yaml` и `messages.en.yaml`. Ну и заполняем словари:

```
# translations/messages.ru.yaml
Some text: какой-то текст
Hello world: привет мир
```

/////////////////

```
# translations/messages.en.yaml
Some text: кSome text
Hello world:  Hello world
```

*Как формируется правила создания файла перевода, настройка пути - все это можно почитать [тут](https://symfony.com/doc/current/translation.html#translation-resource-file-names-and-locations).*

## Перевод в шаблоне

Ну и в шаблоне (twig файле) переводим так:

```
{{ message|trans }}
```

---

Полезная информация:
- управлять локалью для [сессий](https://symfony.com/doc/current/session/locale_sticky_session.html) пользователя;
- [переводы в шаблонах](https://symfony.com/doc/current/translation.html#translations-in-templates);
- Как работать с локалью [пользователя](https://symfony.com/doc/current/translation/locale.html);
- материалы на [русском](https://symfony.com.ua/doc/current/translation.html) (не уверен что будет работать, но существенно упростит понимание некоторых моментов)

Comment: Большое Вам спасибо за развёрнутый ответ, жаль не могу принять Ваш ответ несколько раз, ещё раз спасибо :)